# .getScript getting the redirect url of javascript

Tags: asp.net, javascript, asp.net-ajax, jquery

I d like to execute a remote javascript which redirects the user to another page on my domain with data that s passes as query string. I want to get this data which is passed on to the page on my domain.

```
        $.getScript('http://site.com/foo.js', function() {
            //foo.js redirects to another page on my domain with data
            // and i d like to capture that data from this function, 
            // at least if i find the parameters that passed on there, i ll be fine.  
        });
```

What to do ?

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/

Comment: Can you clarify how this redirect happens? Does foo.js contain a script that changes window.location.href?

When you say "data that s passes as query string," what is s?

Comment: foo.js does a redirect to my page say : mypage.aspx?a=1&b=2 and so on.

Comment: you are being redirected right? what do you need? to change query string of the redirection?

Comment: can you please read the question ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***I am not very sure if you can make ajax calls from other domains.***

`$.getScript()` This is a shorthand Ajax function, which is equivalent to:

```
$.ajax({
  url: url,
  dataType: 'script',
  success: success
});
```

Why do you need to get the script from the url? cant you make your own implementation, i mean, create a copy and refactor it to your site, change whatever you need, remove whatever you need.

you would have 100% access to anything you want..

is there a requirement that forces you to do it this way?

Comment: +1 - Good call emphasizing the other domains bit, indeed you cannot do this, it's called the same-origin policy: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy

Comment: I m sorry, i appreciate your answer and i know the syntax, but i dont understand why you are giving such an answer. I dont know what to tell you. I m executing the javascript because it s returning data from another company's database, which i dont have access too. simple as that.